# How can I get changes to `/etc/resolv.conf` to persist on Linux Subsystem for Windows?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have no network connectivity as per [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/5). In trying to troubleshoot it, one of the first suggestions is editing `/etc/resolv.conf`. When you initially open the file, it looks something like this:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, remove this line.
nameserver 10.10.0.223
nameserver fec0:0:0:ffff::1
nameserver fec0:0:0:ffff::2
search example.net
```

After editing the file--never being really sure when preference files actually take hold--I exit `bash` and log back in. When I log back in, the file is back to its original factory contents. Things I've tried:

- Running Powershell (from which `bash` is started) as `Administrator`.
- Running `bash` from `cmd`.
- Deleting the first line and leaving a blank line.
- Deleting the first line and the blank line.

Comment: Delete that file and make a new one with nano or vi command.

Comment: It worked! Please make an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The file actually is supposed to be /etc/resolv.conf. The Windows Subsystem for Linux is just a copy of ubuntu, mine is 14.04.5. I tried a couple command line options, but did not have success and am out of time for now to try. Search for ways to change dns via the command line for whatever ubuntu release you have installed in your WSL. Find the version with 'sudo cat /etc/*release' and it will tell you.